# Clojure http-kit get request stuck on multiple async calls

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I have created small example which highlight the problem:

```
(->> (range 0 4)
     (mapv (fn [i]
             (http/get "http://http-kit.org/"
                       (fn [res]
                         (info "first callback")
                         (let [res2 @(http/get "http://http-kit.org/")]
                           (info "second callback ")))))))
```

It's stuck on printing the 4s first callback msg's.

[image]

If I change the range for 0..3 it will work, the sync version also works.

**Update:**

The `(info)` is a `taoensso.timbre` logging library

Comment: I see no issue when running. You get a vector of 4 derefables, 4 "first callback"s are printed, and 4 "second callback"s are printed. As a sanity check, remember that `(range 0 4)` is 4 elements, not 5.

Comment: @Josh Can you try to change range to 10 elements?

Comment: @Josh I think it may vary on diff machines depends on CPU cores. For me I just rebooted my mac and got in response 4 derefables,  4 "first callback"s are printed and then stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue caused because the http-kit client thread pool doesn't relieve the thread until callback function is finished. And so it ends up with run out of threads.

So I started to think how to make callback function quicker and came up with this solution:

I have created async wrapper function for http-kit client get which using `clojure.core.async/chan` in callback to quickly put the result in channel and then wait for it results and execute the heavy callback:

```
(defn async-http-get
  [url opts callback]
  (let [channel (chan)]
    (http/get url opts #(go (>! channel %)))
    (go (callback (<! channel)))
    nil))
```

So now using `async-http-get` instead of `http/get` solve the problem for me.

```
(->> (range 0 4)
     (mapv (fn [i]
             (async-http-get "http://http-kit.org/"
                       (fn [res]
                         (info "first callback")
                         (let [res2 @(http/get "http://http-kit.org/")]
                           (info "second callback ")))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My current hypothesis is that you get into a deadlock by exhausting your thread-pool:

1. You create a thread per outer http/get
2. If you create less requests than available threads in the thread pool, there is room to service at least one inner `http/get` (which will require a new thread)

   1. Or if your first request is completed before you exhaust the thread-pool
3. Once there are no more threads in the thread-pool, the inner `http/get` cannot
   be serviced
4. Since the inner request cannot be completed, the outers are stuck forever

You can check the status of the thread-pool http-kit uses peeking `http/default-pool`. There you can see things like:

```
#object[java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 0x5a99e5c "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5a99e5c[Running, pool size = 8, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 24]"]
```

when you did not get into the deadlock. Or

```
#object[java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 0x5a99e5c "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5a99e5c[Running, pool size = 8, active threads = 8, queued tasks = 8, completed tasks = 28]"]
```

when you did.

I have tested this in my machine (shows 8 as `(.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime))`) and I got the results above. I walked into a deadlock when I run more than 8 requests.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking that this is a problem, have you been able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, in my box with `(.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime))` being 8, if I run more than 8 requests, they get stuck.